# set a variable in jmeter postprocessor and access in command prompt in NON GUI mode

Tags: groovy, cmd, command-line, jmeter, post-processor

Is there any way to set an environmet variable in JMeter  and access outside in command prompt after finishing jmeter script in non gui mode?

I have a script which has name of person which is extracted from JSON Extractor and I want to display extracted name on command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) use `OUT` to print to console, for example for person variable

```
 OUT.println("variable person value=" + vars.get("person"))
```

> OUT - System.out - e.g. OUT.println("message")

Comment: @user-Thanks for the answer,I wanted this for http request->preprocessor or postprocessor